# in what sense is the subject of finite group theory 'algebraic'?

Tags: abstract-algebra

[[cross posted from mse]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4099618/why-is-finite-group-theory-often-included-under-algebra)

the class of all finite groups is not closed under produtcs - example: the product over all finite cyclic groups - thus it is not a [variety of algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)#Birkhoff%27s_theorem), ie, it's not axiomatizable by universal sentences.

in fact more is true: it's not axiomatizable at all, [by a consequence of the compactness theorem for first order theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem#Applications), namely, that a theory having models of arbitrarily large finite size - again, take the cyclic groups - must have an infinite model.

proofs of theorems pertaining to finite but not to arbitrary groups have more of an 'arithmetical flavor' than a '[general nonsensical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_nonsense)' one, and it's not hard to envision the subject being developed inside first-order number theory.

so what is it that makes the subject of finite groups 'algebraic'? why does it appear on, say, syllabi on undergrad and graduate algebra?

Comment: I suspect you're bowing down to a false god when you treat that kind of definition of "algebra" as if it were something known to be somehow correct.

Comment: Oh my--when would an undergraduate, or even graduate student, be allowed to read about the classification of finite simple groups?

Comment: not 'correct', of course [definitions don't have truth values], but it seems reasonable to me; it just seems finite group theory is fundamentally 'arithmetical' in character

Comment: @user52817 ideally after understanding 'simplicity' in terms of 'normal subobjects', and these in terms of kernels [either universal-algebraically/model-theoretically or categorially] + understanding simple groups appear naturally in considering composition series

Comment: Are you going to say next that analysis and combinatorics are not really mathematics because there's not enough general nonsense?

Comment: @AlexanderWoo this seems to be an equivocal take on my point; in any case: first-order arithmetic 'is' finite combinatorics [where finite group theory most probably lives], second-order arithmetic [analysis] is countable [and 'near countable'] combinatorics, and [material] set theories are ['strongly'] infinitary combinatorics; mathematics, of course, but of a different flavor

Comment: @ac15 - From where I sit, the entire purpose of general nonsense is that it takes complicated problems, peels away the obfuscation, and exposes their combinatorial kernel.  General nonsense that doesn't have a combinatorial kernel feels vacuous.  Then again, I'm an algebraic combinatorialist.

Comment: @mweiss yes, you are [also note that 'simple' has a specified meaning in this context, cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group]

Answer (score 7):

Typically, students learn about finite groups long before they think of "variety of algebras" or "compactness theorem".  I suppose you also want to exclude fields from "algebra"?

I would say: topics for an algebra syllabus are chosen according to how useful they are; not according to how they fit into some general framework.

Comment: in this sense fields are not 'algebraic' either - witnessed by non closure under products, division being only a partial function, etc - even if axiomatizable; but i understand a field is really studied via its modules/spaces and commutative algebras, these being (generally non finitely axiomatizable) varieties, so there's no 'problem' in this case; more broadly, do you mean it's more a question of historical and pedagogical character than of a conceptual one?

Comment: Correct.  Mathematics students are much more likely to use finite groups in their future studies, than they are to use varieties of algebras.